# What is the difference between MsgBox() and MessageBox.show() in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to display a title on my message box i tried this code
`MsgBox('Cannot Conncet to the db',"Conncetion Error!")`
but it gives me a error, so i read on some blog they included 1 as an addtional parameter inside the msgBox
 `MsgBox('Cannot Conncet to the db',1,"Conncetion Error!")` .
why that addtional parameter is needed.

Comment: MsgBox is a VB6 compatibility method, makes it easy to get old code converted.  It's okayish to use it, but you're better off using MessageBox in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference; `MsgBox()` is just made for users who are somehow familiar with VB6 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You need the three parameters because the VB.NET MsgBox function takes either one parameter (Prompt) or three parameters (Prompt, Buttons, Title).

See [MsgBox Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN for details on the parameters and a number of examples.

To display just the title you might write the following (notice the empty `Buttons` parameter):

```
MsgBox("Cannot Connect to the db", ,"Connection Error!")
```

I'll also add here that you might want to `Or` the various `MsgBoxStyle` options for your Buttons parameter; doing so makes your code a bit easier to read over using integer values.  The link has examples.